# MVC Paging lost navigation after clicking next or previous page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, paging

I have a strange error (at least to me) with the paging in MVC. I have Index page is a list of companies, and there is a link for detail information of a company. Everything is correct with the first page, for example:

```
http://localhost/enterprise/company/Detail?entityid=45
```

But when I click Next Page or navigate to other page, the view company is disappeared, as follow

```
http://localhost/enterprise/Detail?entityid=50
```

I don't have a clue why this error occurs. Below is my paging's code

```
@Html.Pager(Html.PaginationViewModelFrom(Model.Nodes.GetEnumerator(), (IPaginable)Model)).QueryParam("Index").First("First Page").Last("Last Page").Next("Next Page").Previous("Previous Page").Format("List of companies {0} - {1} from total {2}").SingleFormat("{0} from {1} Companies ")
```

Any thought appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What library are you using for paging? So form where the `@Html.Pager` method come from?

Comment: You might have missed to include 'Controller' name in your mapping URL along with 'Action' name. Just include 'Controller' name in mapping URl and try again.

Comment: @nemesv: it is HtmlHelper, the method is HtmlHelper.Pager

Comment: @RanjithKumarGovarthanan: I did use Controller name, but the error happens, I don't know why